# arangojs collections() errors return

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I'm totally green with it all. Sorry, but I cant get this thing to work at all node.js + arangojs >

```js
const myColl = async () => {//new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const db = await new Database({
            url: "http://localhost:8529",
            databaseName: "testDB",
            auth: {username: "userTest", password: "userTest"},
        });
        console.log(db)
        try {
            let collection = await db.collections();
            console.log(collection);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Failed to login db ", err)
        return
    }
}
myColl()
```

I just end up with :

```
Database {_analyzers: Map(0), _collections: Map(0), _graphs: Map(0), _views: Map(0), _connection: Connection, ...}
icAccountController.js:23
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8529 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1237:16) at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {errno: -4078, code: "ECONNREFUSED", syscall: "connect", address: "::1", port: 8529, ...}
```

Comment: did you created server on the local machine ?

Comment: yep I have local arango that seems to be running. if I do ```console.log("isArangoDatabase : " + db.isArangoDatabase)
``` I get true so database seems to be.. valid? not sure...

Comment: The error message shows a failing tcp6 connection.  Can you make sure the server is listening on tcp6? My local install is only listening on tcp (v4) (on linux check the output of `sudo tcpdump -nap | grep arangod`); Or simply set `endpoint = tcp://[::]:8529` in your arangod.conf, restart the server and try your code again.

Comment: @TomRegner Thank you! I've checked it out. I'm on windows atm... so no linuxes here yet.  I can access arango via > http://localhost:8529/ in my chrome... but not sure about tcp thini.... It should.. work as is no ?

Comment: I got it working! Changed address to > ```http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529```

Comment: Hmm @Dariusz for some reason that also did the trick for me. replacing http://localhost with http+tcp:127.0.0.1, but how is that? My code did not change since a couple a months ago when I last ran it successfully. So it must be a change in Windows causing this.